How to perform login and access protected pages using Jsoup in Java?
I am developing a web crawler in Java using Jsoup and facing challenges logging into websites requiring authentication. My goal is to log in to the website, capture the session cookies, and use these cookies for further requests to access protected pages.
I want to share network packets that use the connection to explain myself;
After the first request to the web page,  I take this response
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: BlazingFastWeb
Set-Cookie: BlazingWebCookie=XVUXIwf2lb6sfq1sd9e; 
Domain=.leakbase.io; Path=/

<!DOCTYPE html> 
   html page ....


  <script src="/bf.jquery.max.js"></script>
        <form id="bf-form" action="/blzgfst-shark/" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" id="bfu" name="bfu"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="bf-answer" name="blazing_answer"/>
      </form>
    <form id="bf-form" action="/blzgfst-shark/" method="get">
         <input type="hidden" id="bfu" name="bfu"/>
         <input type="hidden" id="bf-answer" name="blazing_answer"/>
     </form>
    <script>
    (function(){
    var onReady = function( callback ){
        var addListener = document.addEventListener || document.attachEvent,
            eventName = document.addEventListener ? 'DOMContentLoaded' : 'onreadystatechange';
        addListener.call(document, eventName, function(){ callback(); }, false );
    }
    onReady(function(){
      var content = document.getElementById('bf-content');
      setTimeout(function(){
        var t,r,a,f,r;
        t = document.createElement('div');
        t.innerHTML="<a href='/'>x</a>";
        t = t.firstChild.href;
        r = t.match(/https?:\/\//)[0];
        t = t.substr(r.length);
        t = t.substr(0,t.length-1);
        a = document.getElementById('bf-answer');
        f = document.getElementById('bf-form');
    r = document.getElementById('bfu');
    r.value = "/";var _0xf8c2=['value'];(function(_0x4e0014,_0x2fd79f){var _0xc27aa=function(_0x466f85){while(--_0x466f85){_0x4e0014['push'](_0x4e0014['shift']());}};_0xc27aa(++_0x2fd79f);}(_0xf8c2,0x12b));var _0x2f8c=function(_0x54b814,_0x35fe0e){_0x54b814=_0x54b814-0x0;var _0x8cc65=_0xf8c2[_0x54b814];return _0x8cc65;};a[_0x2f8c('0x0')]=0x2394+0x2140*0x3f65;

        f.submit();
      }, 5100);
    });
  })(); </script>

After the response, /bf.jquery.max.js is worked automate and create blazing_answer and bfu to use in next request:
GET /blzgfst-shark/?bfu=%2F&blazing_answer=1380356 HTTP/1.1
Host: leakbase.io
Cookie: BlazingWebCookie=XVUXIwf2lm6aXiF3EqpJoAaDil11wdDv3U4JkxWzKZc0ybdwUMuhxhb6sfq1sd9e; xf_csrf=sQ7mqPb0eDnNjPqQ

and after this request I take response that include BlazingPuzzleCookie
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: BlazingFastWeb

Set-Cookie: BlazingPuzzleCookie=bjjiM8jQBUuHeSQXHomjuDKZLBiWWnCbkA9jBZAItHfFr5Ttm; 
Expires=Sun, 
Domain=.leakbase.io; 
Path=/

Finally I can send request to connect webpage and take session cookie ;
Request:
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: leakbase.io
Cookie: BlazingWebCookie=XVUXIwf2lm6aXiF3EqpJoAaDil11wdDv3U4JkxWzKZc0ybdwUMuhxhb6sfq1sd9e; xf_csrf=sQ7mqPb0eDnNjPqQ; BlazingPuzzleCookie=bjjiM8jQBUuH4rksNsnxnrZ5R6feSQXHomjuDKZLBiWWnCbkA9jBZAItHfFr5Ttm

Response:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: BlazingFastWeb
Set-Cookie: session=RIMpljXe8C9k7X6t_krJ9lKiiLs0.;

<!DOCTYPE html>

After all process, I want to login this webpage with jsoup. Here post request for login :
POST /login/login HTTP/1.1
Host: leakbase.io
Cookie: BlazingWebCookie=XVUXIwffq1sd9e; xf_csrf=sQ7mQ; BlazingPuzzleCookie=bjjiM8jQBZAItHfFr5Ttm; _ga=G2183111; _gid=GA122183111; session=D4kCxe-tw..|1|24B-o_VjfshLRcaI.; _ga_F2KL69.0.0.0

_xfToken=17846%2C2b5b0fc79920ff43&login=example&password=example&remember=1&_xfRedirect=httpFleakbase.io%2F

And my code here:

public class LeakbaseLogin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Step 1: Initial connection to get cookies and response
            String url = "https://leakbase.io/";
            Connection.Response initialResponse = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .execute();

            // Save initial cookies
            Map<String, String> initialCookies = initialResponse.cookies();

            // Parse the initial response to get the document
            Document initialDoc = initialResponse.parse();

            // Step 2: Extract bfu and blazing_answer values from the form
            Element bfuElement = initialDoc.select("input[name=bfu]").first();
            Element blazingAnswerElement = initialDoc.select("input[name=blazing_answer]").first();

            // Extract values
            String bfu = bfuElement != null ? bfuElement.attr("value") : "";
            String blazingAnswer = blazingAnswerElement != null ? blazingAnswerElement.attr("value") : "";

            // Step 3: Make the second request using initial cookies and extracted values
            String secondUrl = String.format("https://leakbase.io/blzgfst-shark/?bfu=%s&blazing_answer=%s", bfu, blazingAnswer);
            Connection.Response secondResponse = Jsoup.connect(secondUrl)
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .cookies(initialCookies)
                    .execute();

            // Save cookies after the second request
            Map<String, String> secondCookies = secondResponse.cookies();

            // Step 4: Make the third request using all cookies
            String thirdUrl = "https://leakbase.io/";
            Connection.Response thirdResponse = Jsoup.connect(thirdUrl)
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .cookies(secondCookies)
                    .execute();

            // Save final cookies
            Map<String, String> finalCookies = thirdResponse.cookies();

            // Step 5: Extract _xfToken from the final response
            Document finalDoc = thirdResponse.parse();
            Element xfTokenElement = finalDoc.select("input[name=_xfToken]").first();
            String xfToken = xfTokenElement != null ? xfTokenElement.attr("value") : "";

            // Step 6: Make the POST request to login
            String loginUrl = "https://leakbase.io/login/login";
            String username = "example";
            String password = "example";
            String encodedPassword = URLEncoder.encode(password, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
            String encodedXfToken = URLEncoder.encode(xfToken, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());

            Connection.Response loginResponse = Jsoup.connect(loginUrl)
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .cookies(finalCookies)
                    .data("_xfToken", encodedXfToken)
                    .data("login", username)
                    .data("password", encodedPassword)
                    .data("remember", "1")
                    .data("_xfRedirect", "https://leakbase.io/")
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    .execute();

            // Print the final response to verify login
            Document loginDoc = loginResponse.parse();
            System.out.println(loginDoc);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

I have some problem firstly I can't take bfu  and blazing_answer to use taking BlazingPuzzleCookie;  Also I'm not sure other parts can work.
I tried to write the js code in my code but didn't work, I don't  know how I can take blazing_answer?  Also, I tried to manually set cookies and connect to log in, but I always connect the first page that has a script to produce blazin_answer.
   // Step 1: Manually set the initial cookies
            Map<String, String> initialCookies = new HashMap<>();
            initialCookies.put("BlazingWebCookie", "XVUXIwf2lm6aXiFdwUMuhxhb6sfq1sd9e");
            initialCookies.put("xf_csrf", "sQ7jPqQ");
            initialCookies.put("BlazingPuzzleCookie", "bjjiM8jQBUuH4rknCbkA9jBZAItHfFr5Ttm");
            initialCookies.put("_ga", "G22183111");
            initialCookies.put("_gid", "GA1.1722183111");
            initialCookies.put("session", "D4kB-o_VjfshLRNoOHxNiAV_icaI.");
            initialCookies.put("_ga_F2KL613JG6", "GS.0.0");

            // Step 2: Initial connection to get the response and tokens
            String url = "https://leakbase.io/";
            Connection.Response initialResponse = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .cookies(initialCookies)
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .execute();

How I can log in to this webpage and other pages that have used a script to produce tokens like this page?
